# In a slightly more scientifically advanced society. Would half human be discriminated

Tags: internal-consistency, society, humans, economy, mythical-creatures

My universe has a slightly more scientifically advanced human world where human had just won a war against sentient dragons (threats of nuclear MAD) from another dimension AND aliens from another planet(with a one-shot superweapon created from O-parts) in two separate wars and started to think they are more superior than other races. During the wars and after it, it was discovered that there are some half-human hidden from the modern soceity andl live a medival lifestyle (they did not participate in the wars due to their lack of tech). Then, some human also started to transform into half-human due to evil scientists or the after effect of the O-parts superweapon (unknown to the human for now). Would these half-humans be discriminated? (range from racial segregation to enslavement)

The conditions are:

1. This human society is like our own in the ways of thinking, with the same nations and the same histories. However, due to the development of new technology, they have better 3D printing and robotic technology. Thus, they can and are replacing a lot of workers.
2. This human society is still recovering from the collasp of economy due to the wars and they suffer (collectively) large amount of casualty.
3. The half humans can be from human with animal ears, eyes and tails on their body like in Japari Park to anthro animals. Mostly are land based animals like rabbits, cat, dog, bear, deer, and raccoons.
4. The hidden half-human do know modern technology, but they just chose not to use it in favor of a less environmentally consuming lifestyle.
5. All half-humans are good looking with the young, minor half-humans are considered "moe" by anime standard. Also, the hidden ones are very naive and don't have discrimination within their society.

Even if they would not be discrinimated during the recovery period, would they ever be?

Comment: You can write a story where both us and no would work. Would you prefer specific result and answers that shows how to get there? Or best guess? But I'm not sure if anyone can reliably extrapolate experiences to cover war with dragons.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about O-parts or threats of MAD.

Generally humans discriminate to either 1: reduce a perceived threat or 2: reinforce solidarity within the discriminating group - "we are not like *those* people". This latter is always for political or economic gain.   I think with two very recent bizarre and nonhuman "other" belligerent groups there would be less need for one group of humans to define a different group as "the other".  I recently watched Independence Day 2 and for me the best thing in that movie was that all the humans were on the same side, all over the world.  Nothing unites like a common enemy.

Eventually, though, the animal people might be a target for discrimination.  The problem is that they are not culturally different nor is their difference by choice so they are not as "other" as a group defined by different culture, religion or expressed sexual preference.
They are just funny looking.  In the west they would be discriminated against in the offhand way fat people or ugly people are discriminated against.  There are countries where being an albino can get you killed for your magic body parts, and I think in benighted parts of the world the animal people would meet similar problems.

Back to 1: The perceived threat might apply. If these half humans are hidden away then they are about the same as Andaman islanders are to the western world - interesting but not really relevant to day to day life.  But if your neighbors start turning into these things then the question is contagion.  It becomes like leprosy.  Can my kids catch it?  I suspect until the etiology for the change was nailed down these new half-humans would be kept in quarantine camps.  Which is discriminatory but also sensible: within living memory we did that to persons with tuberculosis and those laws are still on the books.

I do not think the new half humans would be sent off to live with the old.  These new ones would culturally be the same as the people they grew up with and have nothing in common with the medieval hidden ones.  They would be kept quarantines with each other but able to converse with visiting loved ones via safe mechanisms - probably sort of like prisons.

Comment: I was thinking that due to advanced technology, there will be less need for workers, so human workers might discriminate these half-humans. Also, due to some other literature I have seen, the rich and the powerful might like to enslave these people due to their cute look(I will edit my post) for very disturbing purpose. And animes like GATE, thus the JSDF fought there did show a human society (in Roman Era) discriminate half-humans. And the medival half-human do understand modern tech-they just decided not to use it(again, I would edit my problem).

Comment: and wasn't discrimination originated because of a "us" vs "them" thinking? The humans have just won a bloody war against "others" so wouldn't they be quite xenophobic?

Comment: @FaitoDayo Why? Their foes in the wars were non-human and not from Earth. Half-humans are partially human and belong to Earth, Any xenophobia would be against more non-human beings. Half-humans hardly count. DIscrimination arises from imbalances in political and economic power. There's no reason why half-humans might be considered as part of us and not them.

Answer (score 1):

> Even if they would not be discriminated during the recovery period, would they ever be?

Yes, it inevitable. As a halfcaste I am discriminated against by both sides of my ancestry both by individuals and legislation, that's just the reality of life for many people. Every group wants to feel superior to something. Particularly if the 'different' people are good looking, or talented, or otherwise have something that can add jealousy to the mix.

The caste system is most inflexible and formalised in India, but it's very much alive in some form or other everywhere.

Comment: But would it go into enslavment?